# Не могу вставить R.String в Toast

Tags: java, android, android-toast

Столкнулся с проблемой, у меня в классе есть `Toast`, приложение поддерживает множество языков, и если я вставляю текст в `Toast` так:

---

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

---

То соответственно на английской версии приложения сообщение будет на русском языке, вместо этого я хочу поместить туда ссылку со `String` файла, но никак не могу, гуглил, выдало ответы `getActivity.getResource.getString(R.string.message)` или просто `getResource.getString`, `getString` ни одни из способов не работает, как только должен вызваться `Toast` приложение падает. Я так полагаю что если я смогу туда вставить ссылку то на соответствующем языке будет выдергиваться текст из нужной папки локализации? Но как туда вставить ссылку?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно просто передать id ресурса, т.е:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Ну разумеется это был первый стандартный вариант который я пытался реализовать, но тем не менее `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f080022`

Comment: @McDaggen совсем не разумеется, т.к. этот вариант вы не указали в вопросе. Значить или у вас нет ресурса с таким именев в R.string., или глючит студия. Сделайте Build -> Clean Project, затем Build -> - Rebuild Project, чтобы пересобрался заново файл R.

Comment: Гениально. Заработало